# Opening in a new tab through <Redirect /> component of react router

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

React Router Link component takes in `target="_blank"` to open the page in a new tab. Is there a way to do the same with the Redirect component?

The way my components are set up, I can't wrap `Link` around the component in question (there is a button on the component, clicking on which also redirects, which I don't want) that's why I'm using `Redirect` instead, but can't find a way to open the new URL in a new tab, How can it be done?

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a way to do the same with the Redirect component?

**Short answer:**

No.

**Bit longer:**

Technically [`<Link>`](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/packages/react-router-dom/docs/api/Link.md) creates an `<a>` tag for you which works with `target="_blank"`. From the docs:

> Provides declarative, accessible navigation around your application.

[`<Redirect>`](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/packages/react-router/docs/api/Redirect.md) is used for something else, as the documentation states:

> Rendering a `<Redirect>` will navigate to a new location. The new location will override the current location in the history stack, like server-side redirects (HTTP 3xx) do.

So in summary `<Redirect>` is updating the history, `<Link>` is used as an anchor tag. At the end of the day if you really need to use `target="_blank"` then I would suggest to use `<Link>` or create an `<a>` tag for that purpose.

Earlier I have create a GitHub repository which represents redirect options, please find it below:
https://github.com/norbitrial/react-router-programmatically-redirect-examples

I hope that helps!