# React-router: How to manually invoke Link in new window?

Tags: reactjs, router

I'm using connected react router, and i want to trigger an opening of a new window tab inside a function and not by a direct click on the Link component supplied by the router library.

I have read through the docs of [reactrouter.com](https://reactrouter.com/web/api/Link/others), but i have not been successful in finding a solution.

How can i trigger an opening of a new window tab inside a function, preferably using the react router library?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Opening in a new tab through <Redirect /> component of react router](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59602771/opening-in-a-new-tab-through-redirect-component-of-react-router)

Comment: Thanks, but no. It indicates that it's not possible using <Redirect/>.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure how you would with reactrouter but you could simply use the snippet below. React router is really built around the idea of Single Page Applications.

```js
window.open(`${url}`, "_blank");
```